# How to capitalize "Add to Cart" text?

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, theme, custom

I have tried to edit the title and make all the letters capitalize in file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml but it doesn't works on the frontend. The add to cart is visible as "Add To Cart", And I want it like "ADD TO CART"

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the translate.csv file in the following path `/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/locale/en_US`  and copy and paste `"Add to Cart", "ADD TO CART"` in the file. Save and refresh the page.

I am posting this as an answer because you have used this method.

I recommend that you try it via css though like @R.S suggested though.

Answer (score 4):

Using css would be a better option

e.g

```
.catalog-category-view button.btn-cart span {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest this as a better answer. Changing the translation file works, but simply changing the presentation via CSS makes more sense.

Comment: I changed in styles.css but its still same

Comment: Take a look at How to Use Google Chrome Inspect Element Tool see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnWL2d9bGPk

Comment: Thanks and I know how to work with inspect element.
but you just killed my reputation by 2 points..

Comment: @pspahn Out of curiosity why is editing the css a better answer?

Comment: editing that will also make his proceed to checkout button all upper case to.

Comment: @StevenLynn I know it would, you just need to put `.catalog-category-view` before it

Comment: @R.S Oh gosh! I didn't notice that there!

Comment: Changing the CSS makes sense because you aren't changing the text. Semantically, the button should say "Add to Cart" since that is what it is. You don't want to change the semantic meaning, you're simply changing how the text is displayed. It's no different than wanting to change its color or font.

Comment: @Pspahn Ah I see. Interesting. I did not think about it like that. The Translate file actually changes the text to whatever you want. Makes sense to use CSS for this. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

Locate the translation file @ `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv` and seek the line:

`Add to Cart,Add to Cart`
or
`"Add to Cart","Add to Cart"`

(i.e. with quotes or not)

Change to:

`Add to Cart,ADD TO CART`
or
`"Add to Cart","ADD TO CART"`

Comment: there is no "en_US in app/local
there is only de_DE, es_ES, fr_FR, pt_BR, ru_RU, zh_CN

Comment: try this path: /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/locale/en_US

Comment: @StevenLynn found en_Us under many locations but picked the one that is in my theme and there is no mage_catalog.csv but translate.csv infact there is no mage_catalog.csv in any files

Comment: translate.csv is what you want to add that too.

Comment: In translate.csv add: "Add to Cart", "ADD TO CART"

Comment: @StevenLynn there isn't add to cart in translate.csv. there are wishlist, my account, view all, compare, etc etc but not add to cart

Comment: I second the translate.csv approach as it won't be overwritten in an upgrade.

Comment: I know! Just copy and paste "Add to Cart", "ADD TO CART" into the file and save it. The translate file looks for all instances of "Add to Cart" and replaces it with "ADD TO CART"

Comment: @StevenLynn it worked.
thanks a lot mate. you are awesome
Can you help me a little bit in checkout page bro, I would really apprecaite that.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you need help with? I can try.

Comment: @StevenLynn I am working on horizontal checkout, I added some changes to styles.css and now the checkout is like this http://www.h-o.nl/blog/improved_magento_one_page_checkout_design_css_only but I also want the shopping cart in the right sidebar. I asked this question earlier also but didn't got anything. Here's what I want http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32110/how-do-i-customize-checkout-to-horizontal-checkout